# SQL remove middle characters

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Simple question, not so simple answer!  I have a bunch of dates... how do I remove the middle numbers (which are incorrect) so I just have Week 3, 2011/2012 etc? Thanks!

```
Reporting_Week_Name
Week 52, 2010/2011/2012
Week 52, 2010/2011/2012
Week 1, 2011/2011/2012
Week 1, 2011/2011/2012
Week 1, 2011/2011/2012
Week 1, 2011/2011/2012
Week 1, 2011/2011/2012
Week 1, 2011/2011/2012
Week 1, 2011/2011/2012
Week 2, 2011/2011/2012
Week 2, 2011/2011/2012
Week 2, 2011/2011/2012
Week 2, 2011/2011/2012
Week 2, 2011/2011/2012
Week 2, 2011/2011/2012
Week 2, 2011/2011/2012
Week 3, 2011/2011/2012
Week 3, 2011/2011/2012
Week 3, 2011/2011/2012
Week 3, 2011/2011/2012
Week 3, 2011/2011/2012
Week 3, 2011/2011/2012
Week 3, 2011/2011/2012
Week 4, 2011/2011/2012
Week 4, 2011/2011/2012
Week 4, 2011/2011/2012
Week 4, 2011/2011/2012
Week 4, 2011/2011/2012
Week 4, 2011/2011/2012
Week 4, 2011/2011/2012
Week 5, 2011/2011/2012
Week 5, 2011/2011/2012
Week 5, 2011/2011/2012
Week 5, 2011/2011/2012
Week 5, 2011/2011/2012
Week 5, 2011/2011/2012
Week 5, 2011/2011/2012
Week 6, 2011/2011/2012
Week 6, 2011/2011/2012
Week 6, 2011/2011/2012
Week 6, 2011/2011/2012
Week 6, 2011/2011/2012
Week 6, 2011/2011/2012
Week 6, 2011/2011/2012
Week 7, 2011/2011/2012
Week 7, 2011/2011/2012
Week 7, 2011/2011/2012
Week 7, 2011/2011/2012
Week 7, 2011/2011/2012
Week 7, 2011/2011/2012
Week 7, 2011/2011/2012
Week 8, 2011/2011/2012
Week 8, 2011/2011/2012
Week 8, 2011/2011/2012
Week 8, 2011/2011/2012
Week 8, 2011/2011/2012
Week 8, 2011/2011/2012
Week 8, 2011/2011/2012
Week 9, 2011/2011/2012
Week 9, 2011/2011/2012
Week 9, 2011/2011/2012
Week 9, 2011/2011/2012
Week 9, 2011/2011/2012
Week 9, 2011/2011/2012
Week 9, 2011/2011/2012
Week 10, 2011/2011/2012
Week 10, 2011/2011/2012
Week 10, 2011/2011/2012
Week 10, 2011/2011/2012
Week 10, 2011/2011/2012
Week 10, 2011/2011/2012
Week 10, 2011/2011/2012
Week 11, 2011/2011/2012
Week 11, 2011/2011/2012
Week 11, 2011/2011/2012
Week 11, 2011/2011/2012
Week 11, 2011/2011/2012
Week 11, 2011/2011/2012
Week 11, 2011/2011/2012
Week 12, 2011/2011/2012
Week 12, 2011/2011/2012
Week 12, 2011/2011/2012
Week 12, 2011/2011/2012
Week 12, 2011/2011/2012
Week 12, 2011/2011/2012
Week 12, 2011/2011/2012
Week 13, 2011/2011/2012
Week 13, 2011/2011/2012
Week 13, 2011/2011/2012
Week 13, 2011/2011/2012
Week 13, 2011/2011/2012
Week 13, 2011/2011/2012
Week 13, 2011/2011/2012
Week 14, 2011/2011/2012
Week 14, 2011/2011/2012
Week 14, 2011/2011/2012
Week 14, 2011/2011/2012
Week 14, 2011/2011/2012
Week 14, 2011/2011/2012
Week 14, 2011/2011/2012
Week 15, 2011/2011/2012
Week 15, 2011/2011/2012
Week 15, 2011/2011/2012
Week 15, 2011/2011/2012
Week 15, 2011/2011/2012
Week 15, 2011/2011/2012
Week 15, 2011/2011/2012
Week 16, 2011/2011/2012
Week 16, 2011/2011/2012
Week 16, 2011/2011/2012
Week 16, 2011/2011/2012
Week 16, 2011/2011/2012
Week 16, 2011/2011/2012
Week 16, 2011/2011/2012
Week 17, 2011/2011/2012
Week 17, 2011/2011/2012
Week 17, 2011/2011/2012
Week 17, 2011/2011/2012
Week 17, 2011/2011/2012
Week 17, 2011/2011/2012
Week 17, 2011/2011/2012
Week 18, 2011/2011/2012
Week 18, 2011/2011/2012
Week 18, 2011/2011/2012
Week 18, 2011/2011/2012
Week 18, 2011/2011/2012
Week 18, 2011/2011/2012
Week 18, 2011/2011/2012
Week 19, 2011/2011/2012
Week 19, 2011/2011/2012
Week 19, 2011/2011/2012
Week 19, 2011/2011/2012
Week 19, 2011/2011/2012
Week 19, 2011/2011/2012
Week 19, 2011/2011/2012
Week 20, 2011/2011/2012
Week 20, 2011/2011/2012
Week 20, 2011/2011/2012
Week 20, 2011/2011/2012
Week 20, 2011/2011/2012
Week 20, 2011/2011/2012
Week 20, 2011/2011/2012
Week 21, 2011/2011/2012
Week 21, 2011/2011/2012
Week 21, 2011/2011/2012
Week 21, 2011/2011/2012
Week 21, 2011/2011/2012
Week 21, 2011/2011/2012
Week 21, 2011/2011/2012
Week 22, 2011/2011/2012
Week 22, 2011/2011/2012
Week 22, 2011/2011/2012
Week 22, 2011/2011/2012
Week 22, 2011/2011/2012
Week 22, 2011/2011/2012
Week 22, 2011/2011/2012
Week 23, 2011/2011/2012
Week 23, 2011/2011/2012
Week 23, 2011/2011/2012
Week 23, 2011/2011/2012
Week 23, 2011/2011/2012
Week 23, 2011/2011/2012
Week 23, 2011/2011/2012
Week 24, 2011/2011/2012
Week 24, 2011/2011/2012
Week 24, 2011/2011/2012
Week 24, 2011/2011/2012
Week 24, 2011/2011/2012
Week 24, 2011/2011/2012
Week 24, 2011/2011/2012
Week 25, 2011/2011/2012
Week 25, 2011/2011/2012
Week 25, 2011/2011/2012
Week 25, 2011/2011/2012
Week 25, 2011/2011/2012
Week 25, 2011/2011/2012
Week 25, 2011/2011/2012
Week 26, 2011/2011/2012
Week 26, 2011/2011/2012
Week 26, 2011/2011/2012
Week 26, 2011/2011/2012
Week 26, 2011/2011/2012
Week 26, 2011/2011/2012
Week 26, 2011/2011/2012
Week 27, 2011/2011/2012
Week 27, 2011/2011/2012
Week 27, 2011/2011/2012
Week 27, 2011/2011/2012
Week 27, 2011/2011/2012
Week 27, 2011/2011/2012
Week 27, 2011/2011/2012
Week 28, 2011/2011/2012
Week 28, 2011/2011/2012
Week 28, 2011/2011/2012
Week 28, 2011/2011/2012
Week 28, 2011/2011/2012
Week 28, 2011/2011/2012
Week 28, 2011/2011/2012
Week 29, 2011/2011/2012
Week 29, 2011/2011/2012
Week 29, 2011/2011/2012
Week 29, 2011/2011/2012
Week 29, 2011/2011/2012
Week 29, 2011/2011/2012
Week 29, 2011/2011/2012
Week 30, 2011/2011/2012
Week 30, 2011/2011/2012
Week 30, 2011/2011/2012
Week 30, 2011/2011/2012
Week 30, 2011/2011/2012
Week 30, 2011/2011/2012
Week 30, 2011/2011/2012
Week 31, 2011/2011/2012
Week 31, 2011/2011/2012
Week 31, 2011/2011/2012
Week 31, 2011/2011/2012
Week 31, 2011/2011/2012
Week 31, 2011/2011/2012
Week 31, 2011/2011/2012
Week 32, 2011/2011/2012
Week 32, 2011/2011/2012
Week 32, 2011/2011/2012
Week 32, 2011/2011/2012
Week 32, 2011/2011/2012
Week 32, 2011/2011/2012
Week 32, 2011/2011/2012
Week 33, 2011/2011/2012
Week 33, 2011/2011/2012
Week 33, 2011/2011/2012
Week 33, 2011/2011/2012
Week 33, 2011/2011/2012
Week 33, 2011/2011/2012
Week 33, 2011/2011/2012
Week 34, 2011/2011/2012
Week 34, 2011/2011/2012
Week 34, 2011/2011/2012
Week 34, 2011/2011/2012
Week 34, 2011/2011/2012
Week 34, 2011/2011/2012
Week 34, 2011/2011/2012
Week 35, 2011/2011/2012
Week 35, 2011/2011/2012
Week 35, 2011/2011/2012
Week 35, 2011/2011/2012
Week 35, 2011/2011/2012
Week 35, 2011/2011/2012
Week 35, 2011/2011/2012
Week 36, 2011/2011/2012
Week 36, 2011/2011/2012
Week 36, 2011/2011/2012
Week 36, 2011/2011/2012
Week 36, 2011/2011/2012
Week 36, 2011/2011/2012
Week 36, 2011/2011/2012
Week 37, 2011/2011/2012
Week 37, 2011/2011/2012
Week 37, 2011/2011/2012
Week 37, 2011/2011/2012
Week 37, 2011/2011/2012
Week 37, 2011/2011/2012
Week 37, 2011/2011/2012
Week 38, 2011/2011/2012
Week 38, 2011/2011/2012
Week 38, 2011/2011/2012
Week 38, 2011/2011/2012
Week 38, 2011/2011/2012
Week 38, 2011/2011/2012
Week 38, 2011/2011/2012
Week 39, 2011/2011/2012
Week 39, 2011/2011/2012
Week 39, 2011/2011/2012
Week 39, 2011/2011/2012
Week 39, 2011/2011/2012
Week 39, 2011/2011/2012
Week 39, 2011/2011/2012
Week 40, 2011/2011/2012
Week 40, 2011/2011/2012
Week 40, 2011/2011/2012
Week 40, 2011/2011/2012
Week 40, 2011/2011/2012
Week 40, 2011/2011/2012
Week 40, 2011/2011/2012
Week 41, 2011/2011/2012
Week 41, 2011/2011/2012
Week 41, 2011/2011/2012
Week 41, 2011/2011/2012
Week 41, 2011/2011/2012
Week 41, 2011/2011/2012
Week 41, 2011/2011/2012
Week 42, 2011/2011/2012
Week 42, 2011/2011/2012
Week 42, 2011/2011/2012
Week 42, 2011/2011/2012
Week 42, 2011/2011/2012
Week 42, 2011/2011/2012
Week 42, 2011/2011/2012
Week 43, 2011/2011/2012
Week 43, 2011/2011/2012
Week 43, 2011/2011/2012
Week 43, 2011/2011/2012
Week 43, 2011/2011/2012
Week 43, 2011/2011/2012
Week 43, 2011/2011/2012
Week 44, 2011/2011/2012
Week 44, 2011/2011/2012
Week 44, 2011/2011/2012
Week 44, 2011/2011/2012
Week 44, 2011/2011/2012
Week 44, 2011/2011/2012
Week 44, 2011/2011/2012
Week 45, 2011/2011/2012
Week 45, 2011/2011/2012
Week 45, 2011/2011/2012
Week 45, 2011/2011/2012
Week 45, 2011/2011/2012
Week 45, 2011/2011/2012
Week 45, 2011/2011/2012
Week 46, 2011/2011/2012
Week 46, 2011/2011/2012
Week 46, 2011/2011/2012
Week 46, 2011/2011/2012
Week 46, 2011/2011/2012
Week 46, 2011/2011/2012
Week 46, 2011/2011/2012
Week 47, 2011/2011/2012
Week 47, 2011/2011/2012
Week 47, 2011/2011/2012
Week 47, 2011/2011/2012
Week 47, 2011/2011/2012
Week 47, 2011/2011/2012
Week 47, 2011/2011/2012
Week 48, 2011/2011/2012
Week 48, 2011/2011/2012
Week 48, 2011/2011/2012
Week 48, 2011/2011/2012
Week 48, 2011/2011/2012
Week 48, 2011/2011/2012
Week 48, 2011/2011/2012
Week 49, 2011/2011/2012
Week 49, 2011/2011/2012
Week 49, 2011/2011/2012
Week 49, 2011/2011/2012
Week 49, 2011/2011/2012
Week 49, 2011/2011/2012
Week 49, 2011/2011/2012
Week 50, 2011/2011/2012
Week 50, 2011/2011/2012
Week 50, 2011/2011/2012
Week 50, 2011/2011/2012
Week 50, 2011/2011/2012
Week 50, 2011/2011/2012
Week 50, 2011/2011/2012
Week 51, 2011/2011/2012
Week 51, 2011/2011/2012
Week 51, 2011/2011/2012
Week 51, 2011/2011/2012
Week 51, 2011/2011/2012
Week 51, 2011/2011/2012
Week 51, 2011/2011/2012
Week 52, 2011/2011/2012
Week 52, 2011/2011/2012
Week 52, 2011/2011/2012
Week 52, 2011/2011/2012
Week 52, 2011/2011/2012
Week 52, 2011/2011/2012
Week 52, 2011/2012/2013
Week 1, 2012/2012/2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `charindex` to find the first `/` and `stuff` to remove 5 characters.

```
select stuff(Reporting_Week_Name, charindex('/', Reporting_Week_Name), 5, '')
```

[Data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/278738)

Comment: excellent.  very simple and elegant. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE 
@vcVar AS VARCHAR(500) = 'Week 3, 2011/2011/2012'

SELECT STUFF(@vcVAR , CHARINDEX('/',@vcVar) ,5,'')
```